# why is getMyConnections() function of Rlinkedin package in R not working?

Tags: r

```
> in.oauth<-inOAuth(application_name ="RP",consumer_key  ="xxx",consumer_secret = "xxx")
If you've created you're own application, be sure to copy and paste the following into 
'OAuth 2.0 Redirect URLs' in the LinkedIn Application Details: http://localhost:1410/ 

Authentication complete.
```

> my.connections <- getMyConnections(in.oauth)

```
The following error is appearing when the above function is getting executed in rstudio.
```

Error in x.list[sapply(x.list, is.list)] <- NA :

```
invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link.](https://github.com/mpiccirilli/Rlinkedin) Only 
getProfile, searchCompanies and submitShare function works as per now